# Creating a default Custom Post Template that a Theme can override

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates

I'm in the midst of building a Wordpress Plugin that adds a custom post type, for which I'd like to include a default template to display.  Essentially, this is an event management plugin, and the custom post type is for the Events.  There's a handful of custom meta fields, as well as a child post type (Performances), so without a default template to display them, using it would be pretty unfriendly.  But I would like theme designers to be able to create their own templates for these post types if desired.

Is there a way to use the the template provided with my plugin unless the theme provides its own template?  What's the best practice for doing so?

**Edit:**

Following the advice of Peter Rowell, I caught the template_redirect action and, if the post type was one of mine and a template for it did not exist in the current theme, defaulted to the plugin's template:

```
class FestivityTemplates {

  public static function determineTemplate(){
    global $post;
    $standard_type = strpos($post->post_type, 'fest_');

    if(is_single() && $standard_type !== false) {
      FestivityTemplates::loadSingleTemplate($post);
    }
  }

  private static function loadSingleTemplate($post) {
    $template_name = 'single-'.$post->post_type.'.php';
    $template = locate_template(array($template_name), true);
    if(empty($template)) {
      include(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/Festivity/lib/templates/' . $template_name);
      exit();
    }
  }
}

add_action('template_redirect', array('FestivityTemplates', 'determineTemplate'));
```

Comment: Don't use `template_redirect`. You should use `template_include` instead.

Comment: @StephenHarris Changing this to `template_include` is breaking everything on the site (any other page view) except the layouts that using the layout override http://pastebin.com/LWpSrfim but using `template_include` just prepends content (to any template files placed in the theme directory override) -- the standard `single` view for example is still output below. Should I start a new question for this?

Comment: @Zach - start a new question and link to it here, you have to do things slightly differently with `template_include` :)

Comment: @StephenHarris http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51038/ Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the routine that WP uses for this: [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template). It is in `wp-includes/theme.php` and is called from a number of functions in that file. Those functions are used by `wp-includes/template-loader.php` to select the correct *type* of template based on the current page and then walk up the theme hierarchy looking for a match.

Comment: Question: Is your suggestion to use locate_template() in the plugin to determine if the template exists, then to load my own in the plugin if it does not? That's the approach I'm considering now; I just wanted to make sure I understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: @saalon: Yes. The override logic is the same as child themes, except you are adding the final fallback option of having it in the plugin's directory.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a [bunch of template related filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Template_Filters) (scroll down) you can use to **'hijack' the templates requests and apply your own logic** to them.

Here's an example how to hijack the calls for `single-saalon_events.php` and `archive-saalon_events.php` and use the files from `/your-plugin/templates/` folder instead:

```
# Template for displaying a single event
add_filter( 'single_template', 'saalon_events_single_template') ) ;
function saalon_events_single_template($single_template) {
    global $post;           
    if ($post->post_type == 'saalon_events')
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/saalon_events_single.php';
    return $single_template;
}

# Template for displaying the events archive
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'saalon_events_archive_template') ) ;
function saalon_events_archive_template($archive_template) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('saalon_events') ) // since 3.1
        $archive_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/saalon_events_archive.php';
    return $archive_template;
}
```

Resources:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Template_Filters
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/_single_template

Oh and `template_redirect` Action looks good too!
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Template_Actions

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its best practice but when i faced a similar issue i used the_content hook checked the post type to see if its my custom type and if so i returned just what i wanted.
for example:

```
add_filter('the_content','events_conetnt_display');
function events_conetnt_display($content){
    global $post;
    if (!$post_type == "events"){
        return $content;
    }else{
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'events_conetnt_display' );
        $events_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $new_content = '<div class="event_container">';
        $new_content .= '<div class="event_title">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</div>';
        $new_content .= '<div class="event_description">'.apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content()).'</div>';
        $new_content .= '<div class="event_start_date">'.$events_meta['start_date'].'</div>';
        $new_content .= '<div class="event_end_date">'.$events_meta['start_end'].'</div>';
        //...
        //whatever
        //...
        add_filter('the_content','events_conetnt_display');
        return $new_content;
    }
}
```

and my plugin had an option to let the user decide if he whats to use the_content Hook or if he has a custom template for that something like:

```
if (get_option('use_content_template')){
  add_filter('the_content','events_conetnt_display');
}
```