# Woocommerce getting top level category parent and make all sub categories have the same template and menu

Tags: php, plugins, terms, conditional-tags

I want to get the top level category parent which is "wedgwood" so i give it a different menu and different template that what i wrote so far but it dont apply except on ‘wedgwood’ category wegdwood is my top level category i want this to be applied to all categories underneath it

in header.php

```
if (is_product_category(‘wedgwood’)) {
wp_nav_menu(array(‘menu’=>’wedgwood-menu’ ));
//I want to add here the code that links to another template which is wedgwood-template.php
}
```

in functions.php

```
//register the custom menus
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
array(‘wedgwood-menu’ => __( ‘Wedgwood Menu’ ))
); }
add_action( ‘init’, ‘register_my_menus’ );
```

So please i need a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

WP native function `get_queried_object()` can help you to  **get an ID of a currently displayed term**.

WooCommerce then includes this handy function: `woocommerce_get_term_top_most_parent()` (originated here on [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24795/2110) btw,) that will **get it's top-level parent term**.

I haven't tested the following code but it should provide a good starting point:

```
if ( 'wedgwood' == woocommerce_get_term_top_most_parent( get_queried_object()->term_id )->slug ) {
    // your code-fu here ...
}
```

Regarding the template redirect part of your question - take a look at:
[Creating a default Custom Post Template that a Theme can override](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12295/creating-a-default-custom-post-template-that-a-theme-can-override/12315#12315)

**Reference:**

- **WP Codex:** [get_queried_object()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)
- **Woo Docs:** [woocommerce_get_term_top_most_parent()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_get_term_top_most_parent.html)
- **WPSE:** [Get the the top-level parent of a custom taxonomy term](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term)

Comment: Looks like `woocommerce_get_term_top_most_parent()` doesn't exist anymore!